# Issue with a while loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, boolean

I cant figure out for the life of me why the following code isn't continuing on and would much appreciate any help.

The purpose of this while loop is to ensure that the user enters a valid response to the prompt.

```
boolean flag = true;
while(flag=true){
            flag=true;
            System.out.println("yes to continue. type \"y\" only");
            s = input.nextLine(); // assume user enters either "y" here
            if ( (s.equals("y")){
                flag=false;
            }
        }
/*code im trying to reach*/
```

Comment: while(flag==true) or while(flag)

Answer (score 2):

Change `while(flag=true)` to `while(flag==true)` or simply `while(flag)`.

`=` is the assignment operator. Whereas `==` is the equality operator.

If the statement inside `while` evaluates to `true`, the loop is executed. In your case, `flag` is assigned to `true` and then the value of `flag` is checked. So it is always `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `break`. No need of flags.

A easier and simpler code by modifying your example:

```
while(true)
{
        System.out.println("yes to continue. type \"y\" only");
        s = input.nextLine(); // assume user enters either "y" here
        if (s.equals("y")
        {
            break;
        }
}

// On break (user enters 'y'), the code below this snippet would get executed.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean flag = true;
while(flag){
      System.out.println("yes to continue. type \"y\" only");
      s = input.nextLine(); // assume user enters either "y" here
      if ( (s.equals("y")){
         flag=false;
      }
}
```

You assign flag as true again within the while condition. so it convert to a Neverending loop. No matter what you check inside the loop it is true because you assign true. Try above code it will fixed the issue.

Comment: No, it will not be a `never ending loop`. As soon as the user enters `y`, the `flag` will be assigned a value `false` and during the consequent iteration, the `while(flag)` will be `false` and  would not be executed.